# How to move label to left of input fields?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm working with input fields in **PrimeNG** and not really sure how to move labels to left of fields. Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

**Here's my working code:**

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/r2gTOsUDTz3BzI1JoglD?p=preview)

```
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-4">
            <label>Set Date</label>
            <input id="input" type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="text"> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small column `ui-grid-col4` for the labels and a bigger one `ui-grid-col8` for the inputs :

```
     <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">

        <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
          <span>Phone Ext</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-8">
          <p-inputMask mask="(999) 999-9999? x99999" [(ngModel)]="val5" placeholder="(999) 999-9999? x99999"></p-inputMask>
        </div>

        <br/><br/><br/>

        <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
          <span>Serial Number</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-8">
          <p-inputMask mask="a*-999-a999" [(ngModel)]="val6" placeholder="a*-999-a999"></p-inputMask>
        </div>

    </div>
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DS1GXcoMPxM4FgM0dpQ2?p=preview)

If you want more details about the grid, see the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/responsive-grid/)

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)